# Plotting multiple boxplots group by two columns

Tags: python-3.x

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib as mpl 
import pandas as pd

filepath='E:/PROJECT ON DATA SCIENCE/boxplot/fee.csv';
X=pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=filepath,index_col=0)

X.boxplot(by='stype', column='fee')
X.boxplot(by='pincode', column='fee')
```

Comment: And what is your question? What have you tried?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to boxplot X grouping by both `stype` and `pincode` you can use

```
X.boxplot(column='fee', by=['stype', 'pincode'])
```

Complete code would be

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib as mpl 
import pandas as pd

filepath='E:/PROJECT ON DATA SCIENCE/boxplot/fee.csv';
X=pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=filepath,index_col=0)

X.boxplot(column='fee', by=['stype', 'pincode'])
```

Comment: this was ages ago, but worth a shot. if you wanted to then colour this boxplot according to only one of the "by" (say either "stype" or "pincode") how would you do that?